# for flowtype is there a typeof for functions

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Suppose I have a function

```
export const exampleFunc = (x: Object, y: string) : number => x[y]
```

Is there some way I can get and reuse the exampleFunction type. Ie.

```
const anotherFunc : typeof exampleFunc = (x, y)=>x[y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `typeof` can be used with any value as [its docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/#toc-typeof-type-syntax) state.

The snippet you've added is the correct way to do this, writing:

```
/* @flow */
const exampleFunc = (x: Object, y: string) : number => x[y] 
const anotherFunc: typeof exampleFunc = (x, y) => x[y]
```

in [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5gCmAHgIYC2ADjIQGICuW6YAvGABTEBcYA8gEYArQujwAaMAE8e+AE4BLLAHMAlGB5Z65foVmsAfGGIBtSQF0wGbPjCkscPAAtdDJjzyTKhOFCJkqNK7MbJwSkmoshibmQA), you'll see how it checks out correctly (and adding an illegal call you'll see how the specific types are enforced).